# Unable to save a record with has many through relationship rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i  m trying to save a model which has a has_mnay through relationship with another model, unforunately it dosent allow to save let me explain

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_members, inverse_of: :group
  has_many :members, through: :group_members
end

class GroupMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :member

  validates_presence_of :group, :member
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_members, inverse_of: :member
  has_many :groups, through: :group_members

 validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: true

end
```

so in my console i create a group

```
g = Group.last.dup (duplicating a record)
m = Member.last
g.members << m
g.save!
```

i get this error

```
ActiveRecord :: RecordInvalid: Authentication went wrong: Members email is already used,
```

note that i just have only one member in database
i dont what else needs to be done, i have been trying this for the past one day, i cant find a solution for this

Comment: oh btw i m using rails 4.2.4

Comment: Aren't there some extra callbacks on the `Member` model, like a `before_save`? I'm asking this because as far as I see the code you wrote just adds a record in the `GroupMember` table, and shouldn't create a new member.

Comment: In my case the member is already created, n yes i m trying to add records to GroupMember Table, but it throws the above error

Answer (score 0):

so here is the thing, i had not one member in the database, but many members, and there were lot duplicate emails in the member table, i had added the validation for email after some of the duplicate emails were created. so that is why i was getting the above error 'ActiveRecord :: RecordInvalid: Authentication went wrong: Members email is already used' 
so then in the console i ran a script to make all the member emails uniq and ran those same commands again and this time it worked

turns out that duplicate records prevents saving a record with has many through relationship rails

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error is usually means there's an attribute/method name with the same name as the has_many relationship. I had a column name called "csv_products" which would store a csv file of products to process. And has a relationship called "has_many :products".

Every time I tried to operate on "csv_products" (set it to nil or update it) it would throw this error. I eventually renamed it to "csv_file".